# Progress Dialog and Threading

Tags: android, multithreading

I am targeting Android 4.0 and am communicating with a telemetry device using TCP/IP.  Android 4.0 forces all networking to be done in a separate thread.  First I open a socket, then I contact the device and download some information all from a separate thread.  At this point I want to display a progress dialong to show the progress of downloading more detailed information.  My problem is that I cannot show the progress dialog from anywhere but the main UI.  But, I do not know when I have reached the point in the other thread where I am ready to display the progress dialog.  Is there some way I can check for this from the main UI without tying up the system?

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you wouldn't want to show the progress dialog during the time while you are opening the socket and contacting the device too? Anywho, you can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to send a message back to the main thread from your background one, which you override handleMessage() to react to by doing whatever you want, including showing a progress dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger the dialog on your main ui, you need to use 'context.runOnUiThread()' where context is the reference to your display activity. It's also worth looking into using an AsyncTask.

Here is an android blog post that explains everything in detail: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/05/painless-threading.html

As an aside, you can also just start displaying a indeterminate progress dialog from the start, so the user is never waiting without visual feedback, then switch to the determinate when you know the download details.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you. Also, thank you to all of you that tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Handler, like that :

```
final int PROGRESS_BY = 1;

    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
        {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case PROGRESS_BY :
                    progressBar.setProgress((Integer) msg.obj);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            super.run();
            // do something
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = PROGRESS_BY;
            msg.obj = new Integer(10);
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
            // do something
            [...]
        }
    };
```

Comment: Those are all great suggestions, and I have tried them all. But they do not address my problem. How do I know when to display the progress dialog from the main UI? All of the TCP communication is being done in the background and I do not want to show the progress dialog until a particular background process has finished. What I need to know is how to periodically test that the process has finished from the main UI so I can show the progress dialog? I cannot show the progress dialog from the thread I am waiting on to complete.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` is framework provided utility that is meant for cases like you describe. 
From the other thread, i.e the one in which the async task is executing, you can publish progress using `publishProgress`() method of AsyncTask. Its asynchronous and runs on a different thread but has event callbacks that run on main thread. `OnProgressUpdate`() is the method where you can work with a progress dialog.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html